# Create a VM of an infected machine for anti-malware provider

Tags: virtual-machine, live-usb

We recently suffered a cyberattack which corrupted some of our computers. We left one unrepaired for investigation. While our anti-malware provider is very interested in looking at the computer to inspect the aftermath of the infection, we can't risk turning it on in our network.

Instead, if possible, I'd like to create a bootable USB installed with a compact Linux, boot the machine in a safe environment, and from Linux, create a VM of the infected machine it's attached to. The anti-malware provider has indicated that a VM of the existing infected machine is entirely satisfactory.

Is this possible? If it matters, the infected machine is Windows 10 (what else would it be?).

To summarize the answers below, yes it is possible, but not trivial, and much easier to send the HDD directly (if they accept it, mine wouldn't).

Comment: Have you considered asking this question at [Security Stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com)? They should have expertise on this kind of problems, too.

Comment: Answering this question will take an entire step by step howto detailing a lot of offtopic and quite trivial actions (connect some kind of storage; create a fs on it; copy the image of all the ssds and hard disks on it, etc); better just pack and send them the whole machine with all its hardware and let _them_ figure out what to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to do this is to boot the machine to a live distro with a large enough persistent storage area for installing VirtualBox.

> Things needed: Target system, Live Distro USB with persistent storage, USB to store clone on
>
> Boot with all networking cards un-plugged/removed, if not able to un-plug/remove wired/wireless card/s then change all wifi passwords for the routers it has/had access to before turning the target machine on in case you fail to boot directly to the live distro. Make sure all media needed is installed, ie. target, storage, and live distro...

Power on system

Change BIOS boot order as needed to boot to the live distro. Check manufacturers manual for entering BIOS.

Once within the live distro find out what the drive path is for the system being cloned and the drive you wish to store the image on. You could use `lsblk` for this.

Install VirtualBox on the live distro. `sudo su -` `apt-get install virtualbox`

Then execute the following command:

`VBoxManage convertfromraw /path/to/drive/to/clone /path/to/store/on/MyImage.vdi --format VDI`

> The drive to store the image on should be separate from the live distro and the drive being cloned.

Comment: Thank you. We've determined that it's too much hassle to get this done. They've since found another case and have enough to work with to determine the attack vector and payload. It's malware that provides a known vulnerable driver to compromise and get kernel level access! We'll probably be hearing more of this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** It is certainly possible to create a USB with a bootable Linux especially for this particular purpose. In fact, there are several Linux distributions made specifically for a task that involves forensic analysis and data recovery. If you are in a tech oriented company there should always be several "rescue kits" available on hand, i.e. secure boxes with rescue USBs, OS images, any templates for scripts/databases to get you up and running as quickly as possible, whether its due to a cyberattack or a physical fire.

Please provide some info regarding the type of an attack/system corruption you are dealing with, and I will update this answer with a proper distribution to go with for analysis/recovery.

**2.** Creating a VM of the infected system should be the endgame approach. What I mean by that is you can use a VM to study an infection (in a way similar to studying a deadly virus in a very secure lab) by purposely infecting a clean VM with a given malware.

- First, it likely will not allow you to properly examine the current unknown cyberthreat or determine the attack vectors present at your company,  when you have absolutely no idea what you are dealing with.
- Second, connecting to an infected/compromised VM could always theoretically expose the host to "some" type of an "attack" vector. The attack might be harmless, but it might be of some yet unknown/undiscovered/unpatched type. There have been numerous VM vulnerabilities found in the past, and there will be numerous ones found in the future [VM Advisories](https://www.vmware.com/security/advisories.html) . Hence, it is a good idea for the rescue/host OS doing the analysis to always be a discardable system (stand-alone hardware, live USB stick etc).
- If you don't yet know and understand the actual threat you are dealing with, and better yet have an approach for plugging the hole, always expect the worst case of scenario. Always minimize any chance of the attack being able to restart/continue in any way.

Every day, there are new zero-day vulnerabilities being actively searched for and discovered, and your machine might have just gotten exposed to something so brand new that it is still being analyzed by security experts.

**3.**

> While our security provider is very interested in looking at the computer, we can't risk turning it on in our network.

I don't know how else to put this but if your security provider expects your company/you to set this up for testing, I highly suggest you guys find a new security provider. There are countless reasons for this, but the most important ones you guys should be concerned with are legal, namely current and future liability, as well as chain of custody issues (if this was done by a current/former employee as it most often is).

Comment: They aren't connecting to the machine directly... they're shipping the image to a company who will do that for them.

Comment: Point 3 is the most important one for practical applications. If I already had a contract with an external security provider, I'd just mail them the harddrive.

Comment: @cutrightjm, I hope you are right, but that is just an assumption. There are some serious contradictions in the OP's question, namely "...we have left one unrepaired for investigation..." because it possibly implies that the company personnel had done the repairs themselves on-site  , but the investigation is to be done by their security provider, (which raises a whole other  question regarding what  role this external security provider actually plays). If the disk image is getting shipped then the VM is unnecessary, and the sent image might have serious legal chain of custody issues.

Comment: I added some details I hope will clarify. In particular, we don't yet have the attack vector or attack payload. The security provider has seen a similar attack recently and is trying to figure those details from studying the infected machine. They will deal with isolating the VM, etc. to ensure it doesn't cause any damage. We'll deal with the HD afterwards.

Comment: Also, calling them a "security provider" is a bit inaccurate, better is "anti-malware provider", so have revised accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The anti-malware provider brought to my attention this [VMWare product](https://www.vmware.com/in/products/converter.html) which might do the trick. Will try it out and post the results here for everyone's benefit.

Edit: It's not what I'm looking for! Will follow the commenter's suggestion to use `dcfldd`.

Comment: I would never recommend the use of VMware vCenter Converter when dealing with unknown malware. My recommendation is simply to make a forensic image of the infected disk using `dcfldd` or a similar tool and make that available to your anti-malware vendor.